# Python2.7 Exception "The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program"

Tags: python

```
import Queue
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

BaseManager.register('get_queue', callable=lambda:  Queue.Queue())

manager = BaseManager(address=('', 5000), authkey='abc')
manager.start()
manager.shutdown()
```

This code will throw a exception

```
RuntimeError: 
        Attempt to start a new process before the current process
        has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are on Windows and you have
        forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce a Windows executable.
```

but after I add `if __name__ == '__main__': freeze_support()`
It will throw anther exception, how to fix it?
My os is `window7`

Comment: I doubt that's the entire error message, they don't usually cut off in the middle of a sentence. And you didn't even give us the other message.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This error message is displayed when using multiprocessing with the `'spawn'` start method (default on platforms lacking `fork` like windows), and not protecting your code with a `if __name__ = '__main__'` guard.

The reason is that with the `'spawn'` start method a new python process is spawned, which then in turn has to import the `__main__` module before it can proceed to do it's work. If your program does not have the mentioned guard, that subprocess would try to execute the same code as the parent process again, spawning another process and so on, until your program (or computer) crashes.

The message is not ment to tell you to add the `freeze_support()` line, but to guard your program:

```
import Queue
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

def main():
    BaseManager.register('get_queue', callable=lambda:  Queue.Queue())

    manager = BaseManager(address=('', 5000), authkey='abc')
    manager.start()
    manager.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # freeze_support() here if program needs to be frozen
    main()  # execute this only when run directly, not when imported!
```

Comment: I used your code but it stil raise `EOFError`, This is a part of my console        
`pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x02645470>: it's not found as __main__.<lambda>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "...forking.py", line 381, in main
    self = load(from_parent)
  File "...pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "...pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "...pickle.py", line 880, in load_eof
    raise EOFError
EOFError`

Comment: That's a different problem, not really related to the first one. In essence, you can't use a `lambda` as `callable` argument to `BaseManager.register`, also it's not needed, you can just use `BaseManager.register('get_queue', callable=Queue.Queue)` without lambda.

Comment: Literally took me 45 minutes to figure this out and all I had to do was to add a main() call... Thank you for this response and for explaining the reasoning behind it. It all makes sense now and I can sleep in peace.