# what's different between these two simple python codes? (one works and the other doesn't work)

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

```
import os
import numpy as np
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, current_process


def doubler(number):
    result = number * 2
    proc_name = current_process().name
    print('{0} doubled to {1} by: {2}'.format( number, result, proc_name))

def solve_inverse(np_ndarray_square_matrix):
    inverse_matrix=np.linalg.inv(np_ndarray_square_matrix)
    proc_name = current_process().name
    print('process name :',proc_name,'       ',inverse_matrix)


if __name__=='__main__':
    start_time=time.time()

    dim=100
    thread_num=10

    matrice = [np.random.normal(loc=1.0 , scale=5.0 , size=(dim,dim)) for _ in range(thread_num)]
    procs = []

    for index, matrix in enumerate(matrice):
        proc = Process(target=solve_inverse , args=(matrix,))
        procs.append(proc)
        proc.start()

    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()

    end_time=time.time()

    print('time length :',end_time-start_time)
```

the code above is a simple python code which computes inverse of randomly sampled matrices with multiprocessing. However , the following code doesn't work

```
import os
import numpy as np
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, current_process


def doubler(number):
    result = number * 2
    proc_name = current_process().name
    print('{0} doubled to {1} by: {2}'.format( number, result, proc_name))

def solve_inverse(np_ndarray_square_matrix):
    inverse_matrix=np.linalg.inv(np_ndarray_square_matrix)
    proc_name = current_process().name
    print('process name :',proc_name,'       ',inverse_matrix)


start_time=time.time()

dim=3
thread_num=10

matrice = [np.random.normal(loc=1.0 , scale=5.0 , size=(dim,dim)) for _ in range(thread_num)]
procs = []

for index, matrix in enumerate(matrice):
    proc = Process(target=solve_inverse , args=(matrix,))
    procs.append(proc)
    proc.start()

for proc in procs:
    proc.join()

end_time=time.time()

print('time length :',end_time-start_time)
```

the only difference is whether there is `if __name__=='__main__:` or not.
As far as I know, `if __name__=='__main__:` recognize if this module is imported by the other module or this module run itself. So I thought actually there's no difference between two codes to decide what computer should do. what's wrong?

Comment: And one more question!  It seems that the first code doesn't do 'multi-processing' I mean, multi processing doesn't seem to work at the same time when I watch the time the code takes from start to end. when I increased multiprocessing number, the time increased linearly w.r.t. the number of multiprocessing. I don't know what happend! please help me!

Comment: These answers will help. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29697273/4045933, 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18205006/4045933

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically, every time you make a child process that process starts by importing your script (much as you might `import numpy as np`).

If you don't block off the parts of your script that generates new processes under `if __name__='__main__':`, all those sub-process would spawn their own sub-sub-processes whenever they import the script, which would spawn their own sub-sub-sub-processes and so on until you have . . . well . . .

a Stack Overflow.  And nobody likes them.

Answer (score 1):

`if __name__ == '__main__':` is required for the multiprocessing module to work. See [Programming Guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming), specifically:

> Safe importing of main module
>
> Make sure that the main module can be safely imported by a new Python interpreter without causing unintended side effects (such a starting a new process).