# Is there a way to solve the Run-time error in python while running Multiprocessors which is appearing because I'm not using fork?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, runtime-error

So I'm having this Problem while I'm still new to programming in Python and learning about Multiprocessing and I can't get pass this error. I keep getting this message but I don't know what to do with it.

I was running this code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
processes = []
import os
def square_num():
    for i in range(100):
        i * i

num_processes = os.cpu_count()

for _ in range(num_processes):
    p = Process(target=square_num)   
    processes.append(p)

for p in processes:
    p.start()

for p in processes:
    p.join()

print('end main')
```

After executing the code,I get the following message:

This probably means that you are not using fork to start your child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    ...
```

The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

What I tried to solve this:

I don't if I did exactly as the solution below instructed which I found here on stack overflow while I was searching for a solution to this problem  but I thought it wouldn't work since the error below was
because of not using windows but the latter still same error about proper Idiom which I don't know what it is.

Attempt to start a new process before the current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.
This probably means that you are on Windows and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    ...
```

The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program is not going to be frozen to produce a Windows executable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29697273/8658598

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a platform that uses the *spawn* method to create new processes, then you must put any code at global scope that you do not want the child process to execute (or do not need for it to execute) within a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block. In your code each child process would be recursively attempting to start its own child processes.

```py
def square_num():
    for i in range(100):
        i * i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from multiprocessing import Process, cpu_count
    
    num_processes = cpu_count()

    # Use a comprehension:
    processes = [
        Process(target=square_num)
        for _ in range(num_processes)
    ]

    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

There would be no great harm in not putting the `import` statement within the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block, but there is no need for the child processes to do this import and so I have moved it.